# How can I display the MP4 General Link Field?

Tags: sxa

I want to display the **MP4 video** inside the file and I was trying to do it, but I get the issues when I try to display the field inside the component.

Here is the template:

[image]

So is it possible to get the MP4 file from the `Media` folder and then display it to the component?

The name of the field is `Video Link`. Should I make some new methods or is it easy to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve this something like this.

1. Use `Internal Link Field` rather than using the `Media or Image field`.
2. From the Path of the `Internal Link` get the Video Item and use `MediaManager` to get the URL.

   ```
   MediaItem video = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(videoPath);

   string src = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(video);
   ```

You can refer to this link to find more.

[Video url with Image type Field](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9176/video-url-with-image-type-field)

Comment: Thank you for answering. One question, do you know how to get the path? I am a begineer when it comes to that stuff so sorry if it is a stupid question

Comment: I think this link can help to get the path from Internal Link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394438/sitecore-8-easy-way-to-get-item-in-internal-link

Answer (score 4):

Your question is fully answered in the Sitecore documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/create-a-video-header-background.html

Short version: use Scriban like this:

```
<video autoplay muted loop class="video-background">
  <source src="{{ i_item.video.target.media_url }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This example does assume your field is called video (always best to avoid spaces in the name of your fields btw - you can always use the Title of a field to display a more readable name to the editors) and is of type File (not link).

Comment: Just wanted to add, do look for your field name in the template which you are using. In my case the field was {{i_item.MP4Movie.target.media_url}}, rest all worked fine